# VSTS build associated commits

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Does anyone know how VSTS creates its list of associated commits for a build?

I'm specifically looking for those created when I create a new branch. Currently it seems to just create a list of the past few commits to the branched from branch.

Ideally what I'd like is something akin to `git log master..<commit hash>`.

We were hoping to use this as release documentation by creating a new branch for the release which would contain the full commit history for all work across all branches merged into it but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: It's the commits since the last successful build of that definition.But you're free to call git from your build to generate the additional information.

Comment: You might also find the VSTS Rest API useful.  In particular, the Git commits may help: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits

Comment: Do you solve this issue with our solution?

Comment: I can get the full commit history if I create a new branch and build with it, can you share your steps?

Comment: I did as @ChrisMelinn said: got current build information, then asked for past build runs, selected only these that of my definition, successful, and run on the same branch as my current one. Then I took the top one from received list. And thus I got commit hash from which this successful build was assembled. Then I asked API about commits between these two, and that gave me needed information. Kind of not straightforward, but at least something.

Answer (score 1):

It includes current commit and previous failed build(s) commits if have. For example:

1. Build failed (Comment commit 01), associated changes: commit 01
2. Build failed (Comment commit 02), associated changes: commit 02  commit 01
3. Build succeed (Comment commit 03), associated changes: commit 03 commit 02  commit 01
4. Build succeed (comment commit 04), associated changes: commit 04

So, it won’t include all commits.

To get all commits, you can go to Code=>Select file or folder=>Click history, then the history will be listed.

You also could get commits through REST API (as Chirs Melinn said).

Comment: It's kind of close. But not really. It looks like VSTS uses internally some API that was not exposed (yet?), but try, for example, delete some successful builds and trigger a new one. It will not pick up commits that was associated previously with other builds.

Comment: Another thought would be, what if build was partially successful? Should we count commits included to it or not?